# Solving Linear Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of $$z(z^2+xy)(px-qy)=x^4$$ Let   $F(x,y,z,p,q)=z(z^2+xy)(px-qy)-x^4$. This gives
$$F_p=zx(z^2+xy)$$
$$F_q=-yz(z^2+xy)$$
$$F_r=x^4$$
The Auxiliary equation for the given Linear Pde is $$\frac{dx}{zx(z^2+xy)}=\frac{dy}{-zy(z^2+xy)}=\frac{dz}{(x^4)}$$

But I can't seem to find anything afterwards to get the general solution.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Assuming you mean $p = z_{x}, q = z_{y}$, then you have missed the auxillary equations for $dp, dq$. You can also directly solve the DE resulting from the $dx, dy$ ratios.

Answer (score 1):

As the homogeneous

$$
x F_x-y F_y = 0
$$

has as solution

$$
F=\Phi(z, xy)
$$

choosing the change of variables

$$
\cases{
u=x\\
v=x y\\
w= z}
$$

we get at

$$
F(x,y,z)=G(u,v,w)
$$

and

$$
G_u(u,v,w) = \frac{u^3}{w(v+w^2)}
$$

with solution

$$
G(u,v,w) = \frac{u^4}{4w(v+w^2)}+\Psi(v,w)
$$

or

$$
F(x,y,z) = \frac{x^4}{4z(xy+z^2)}+\Psi(x y,z)
$$